# Socketstream - handling an array with Jade+Hogan templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, hogan.js, socketstream

I am using [Socketstream](https://github.com/socketstream/) default stack with Jade and ss-hogan for templating. I love it, except I can't figure out how to print a list. Example:

client.js

```
html = ss.tmpl['game-full'].render({
  name: 'GTA IV',
  platforms: [{
      name: 'ps3'
    }, {
      name: 'xbox'
    }
  ]
})
```

templates/game/full.jade

```
h1 {{name}} is fine
ul
  li I don't know how to list {{platforms}} here, one per li
```

I'm just a bit confused by the Jade>HTML>Hogan process I think, and not sure what syntax to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way render an item in a list is documented here: https://gist.github.com/fat/1484342#file-gistfile1-html

An example in a SocketStream application can be found here: https://github.com/Anephenix/dashku/blob/master/client/templates/dashboard/nav.jade

Looking at your code, I would suggest trying this:

```
h1 {{name}} is fine
ul
  {{#platforms}}
  li I don't know how to list {{name}} here, one per li     
  {{/platforms}}
```